# Show alert view on another alert view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uialertview

I want to show an alert view on another alert view. My first alert view is custom alert view. Now Problem is when i call second alert view first alert disappears that should not be happened . Please give me a solution for that.

Comment: You should create a custom alert view using basic view.

Answer (score 0):

I simply initialized two alert view with different tags on different methods and in alert view's delegate method. by checking tags i called those methods so on first alert view's cancel action second appears and on second's cancel action first appears.

My problem is solved by this stuff. Because this question is also my so i hope the above trick will be helpful to every body.